# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : best way to pause before resending email

Tags: multithreading, smtp, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, thread-sleep

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. It is not using async. It was supposed to be a learning project, so I kept it simple, but now it's in production (woo). Because of this, I can't just rewrite the whole thing to use async.

In the Log4net stuff we have a SMTP appender that sends an email whenever an error is logged.

If sending the email with the error fails I want to retry

```
public void SendEmail(string messageBody)
{
    bool sent = false;

    // try 3 times to send the email, before failing - EWB
    try
    {
        sent = SendEmailInner(messageBody);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            sent = SendEmailInner(messageBody);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            try
            {
                sent = SendEmailInner(messageBody);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                throw new Exception( "Log4NetSmtpAppender::SendEmail(...) - Failed on try 3 to send email ", ex2);
            }

            if (!sent) 
                throw new Exception( "Log4NetSmtpAppender::SendEmail(...) - Failed on try 2 to send email ", ex );
        }

        if (!sent) 
            throw new Exception( "Log4NetSmtpAppender::SendEmail(...) - Failed all 3 attempts to send email ", e);
    }
}
```

I'd like to pause for 1 second before retrying, but I don't want to block the main thread of the Web API and cause problems with it missing requests.

So `Thread.Sleep(1000)` seems dangerous.

What is the best way to pause for 1 second in this context?

Comment: A few thoughts - without going async, you will block the thread that is handling this request, but that doesn't mean your api won't handle other requests. If you want to build in some retry logic and have cleaner, less nested code, I encourage you to check out the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) library. It makes it fairly easy to implement retries, including with delays between retries in a clean and configurable way.